# Base class of animation

Tags: android, animation

just out of curiosity want to know whats the base class for 2-D animation in android ?
I have searched  through various threads but haven't found a perfect answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main mechanisms you can use for animations in android: tweened and frame-by-frame. For tween there is the abstract [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class in the [view animation package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html). For frame-by-frame there is the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) class in the [graphics drawable package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html).